# SSRS Visual Studio Grid in Designer

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

Everytime I work on an SSRS report in visual studio I have this grid that appears in design mode, on top of the report itself...

[image: grid]

Does anyone know how I can remove this from my view? I know I can click and scroll to reduce the size, but I would like to remove it entirely.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While in design mode:

Menu: Report > View > Parameters (toggle)

[image]

Comment: thanks for answer. do you know what this is used for? Just to display available parameters or something?

Comment: It also allows you to arrange the parameters via drag and drop. I can't say that I like this addition to the tools UI, but it is good to know we can hide it.